# How do you use an svg file to set a shape of a button in javafx?

Tags: svg, javafx

I am attempting to create an image on a button similar to the calendar on `DatePicker`.

I have attempted to use `-fx-shape`, same as the date picker, with an svg path, but it does not seem to be working. The code I have in my css is:

```css
 .time-picker > .toggle-button {
    -fx-shape:"M 43.73,27.84
           C 43.73,28.87 42.90,29.71 41.87,29.71
             41.87,29.71 26.13,29.71 26.13,29.71
             26.13,29.71 26.13,10.11 26.13,10.11
             26.13,9.08 26.97,8.24 28.00,8.24
             29.03,8.24 29.87,9.07 29.87,10.11
             29.87,10.11 29.87,25.97 29.87,25.97
             29.87,25.97 41.87,25.97 41.87,25.97
             42.89,25.97 43.73,26.81 43.73,27.84 Z
           M 56.00,28.00
           C 56.00,43.44 43.44,56.00 28.00,56.00
             12.56,56.00 0.00,43.44 0.00,28.00
             0.00,12.56 12.56,0.00 28.00,0.00
             43.44,0.00 56.00,12.56 56.00,28.00 Z
           M 52.27,28.00
           C 52.27,14.62 41.38,3.73 28.00,3.73
             14.62,3.73 3.73,14.62 3.73,28.00
             3.73,41.38 14.62,52.27 28.00,52.27
             41.38,52.27 52.27,41.38 52.27,28.00 Z";
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: CSS string literals can only span multiple lines, if they end with a backslash. (Not sure if JavaFX supports this at all...)

Answer (score -2):

The best practice when working on a css file is to be sure that your javafx program is using that css file.